# How to change the border's style according to the object's occurrence?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a `ListView`. In this list view, each rectangle represents the tables in a business. These tables can have a receipt. I made the style `{StaticReseource closeTableBorderStyle}` for tables that do not have a receipt. But if the table has an addition, I want to change the style of the table.

`closeTableBorderStyle` code:

```
<Style x:Key="closeTableBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0a7d38"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00d052"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Table class:

```
public class Table
    {
        public int tableID { get; set; }
        public string tablename { get; set; }
        public List<OrderReceipt> tableReceipt { get; set; }
    }
```

ListView:

```
          x:Name="ListViewTableBorder"
          SelectionChanged="ListViewTableBorder_SelectionChanged" 
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <UniformGrid Columns="5"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
         <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                  <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                     <Border Name="Selection" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                     <Border Style="{StaticResource sales_border}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding tablename}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   FontSize="20"/>
                     </Border>
                     <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                           Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                           VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                           SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                  </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

It came to the `Table` class to define a boolean variable named `isTableOpen` and then write an algorithm like below, but I couldn't.

```
if isTableOpen = false
{
   style -> closeTableBorder
}
else
{
   stlye -> openTableBorder
}
```

In summary, if `tableReceipt.Count` > 0, I want the border style to be `openBorderTableStyle`.
Else `tableReceipt.Count` < 0, I want the border style to be `closeBorderTableStyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by giving the target `Border` a name like `TableNameBorder` and add a trigger to the template that sets the `Style` of the border to `closeBorderTableStyle` when `isTableOpen` is `false`.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
   <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
      <Border Name="Selection" Visibility="Collapsed" />
      <Border x:Name="TableNameBorder" Style="{StaticResource sales_border}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding tablename}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="White"
                    FontSize="20"/>
      </Border>
      <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
   </Grid>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isTableOpen}" Value="False">
         <Setter TargetName="TableNameBorder" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource closeTableBorderStyle}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Consider implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `Table` type if you intend to change the properties, otherwise the changes will not be reflected in the user interface. Likewise, if you want to modify your collections at runtime, you should use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`.